# How to perform varying operations on DataFrame rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set in which monetary figures are given in a number of different currencies, eg:

```
ID   X     Currency
1    10    AUD
2    20    NZD
3     5    GBP
4    15    USD
```

I am looking to create a new column which shows all of the values converted into GBP:

```
 ID   X     Currency Converted X
 1    10    AUD      5.5
 2    20    NZD      10.4
 3     5    GBP      5
 4    15    USD      12.3
```

I have a list of tuples containing the currency and exchange rate to GBP:

```
exchange=[(AUD,0.55),(NZD,0.52),(USD,0.82)]
```

Which I have then tried to apply via:

```
 for a,b in exchange:
        df.loc[df['Currency']==a,'Converted X'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['X']*b)
```

Producing the error:

```
KeyError: ('X', 'occurred at index Id')
```

or

```
for a,b in exchange:
        df.loc[df['Currency']==a,'X'] *= b)
```

Producing the error:

```
KeyError: 'Converted X'
```

I have looked at groupby() but I do not want to summarise the data at this point and would like the operation to be carried out on each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with multiple by column `X` by [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) - if need original value `X` if not exist value in dictionary add parameter `fill_value=1`:

```
df['Converted X'] = df['X'].mul(df['Currency'].map(dict(exchange)), fill_value=1)

print (df)
   ID   X Currency  Converted X
0   1  10      AUD          5.5
1   2  20      NZD         10.4
2   3   5      GBP          5.0
3   4  15      USD         12.3
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
df['Converted X'] = df['X']
for a,b in exchange:
        df.loc[df['Currency']==a,'Converted X'] = df['X']*b
print (df)
   ID   X Currency  Converted X
0   1  10      AUD          5.5
1   2  20      NZD         10.4
2   3   5      GBP          5.0
3   4  15      USD         12.3
```

Comment: Oh man I was frustratingly close! Thanks for the quick answer, will tick once the 10 minute minimum has passed

Answer (score 1):

To be safe, I would recommend you add GBP exchange rate into the exchange,

```
exchange.append(('GBP',1))

df['Converted X'] = df['Currency'].map(dict(exchange)).mul(df['X'])
```